# How do I use GraphQL to query the options for a KeystoneJS select field

Tags: graphql, introspection, keystonejs

I have set up a `select` field in KeystoneJS as per the [docs](https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/fields/src/types/select/#select):

```
const { Select } = require('@keystonejs/fields');

keystone.createList('Order', {
  fields: {
    status: { type: Select, options: 'pending, processed' },
  },
});
```

How can I use [introspection](https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/) to get a list of valid options for this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Types in KeystoneJS seem to be named with the following format:

```
<list name><field name>Type
```

Additionally, if the first letter of `<list name>` or `<field name>` are lowercase, these are changed to uppercase. So for the example given in the question, the type name for the field `status` would be:

```
OrderStatusType
```

The available options can then be queried with the following:

```
query {
  __type (name: "OrderStatusType") {
    enumValues {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Tested on a standard KeystoneJS install with a Postgres database.